# Solr data import memory usage

Tags: solr

I am running Solr 3.2 and 4 GB memory. Whenever I start the Solr , it does full import of all the cores and after that every 30 minutes delta import happens. Among 5 cores, 2 cores are having data around 1.6M. Full import takes for those 2 cores more than 20 hours and it is taking all the memory. Because of less memory delta import is not happening for other cores. This leads to restart of the Solr whenever data is updated in DB.

As until commit happens, it won't release the memory, I have given autocommit interval to 5 minutes for those 2 cores. Even though memory is not reduced.

Is there any other configuration I can check?

**Edit 1** My autocommit settings

```
<autoCommit>
  <maxDocs>25000</maxDocs>
  <maxTime>300000</maxTime>
</autoCommit>
```

**Edit 2** jconsole

System information & values from jconsole

- Operating System: Windows 7 6.1
- Architecture: amd64
- Number of processors: 1
- Committed virtual memory: 2,618,508 kbytes
- Total physical memory: 4,193,848 kbytes
- Free physical memory: 669,472 kbytes
- Total swap space: 9,317,672 kbytes
- Free swap space: 2,074,072 kbytes

threads details from jconsole

- Live threads: 201
- Peak: 207
- Daemon threads: 182
- Total threads started: 2,770

Comment: Would you post relevant parts of your configuration files? The `<maxDocs>` within the `<autoCommit>` could also be interesting.

Comment: The other thing is, which Java Version are you using? If you expect older versions of Java to give memory back to the OS, you can wait a long time.

Comment: java 1.6 and   <autoCommit> 
       <maxDocs>25000</maxDocs>
      <maxTime>300000</maxTime> 
     </autoCommit>

Answer (score 0):

Check https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems, especially "Slow startup" part.  I think that's your case.

Comment: Can I ask your PC or server's specification and what's actual free memory that Solr can use? Did you run profiler or VisualVM(jConsole) against Solr to see what's happening? (CPU/MEMORY usage, heap memory size, number of threads, any thread blocking, etc )
IIRC it shouldn't take 20 hours for 1.6M data full import...

Comment: The following values i have taken from jconsole,
Operating System: Windows 7 6.1
Architecture: amd64
Number of processors: 1Committed virtual memory: 
2,618,508 kbytes
Total physical memory: 
4,193,848 kbytes
Free physical memory: 
  669,472 kbytes
Total swap space: 
9,317,672 kbytes
Free swap space: 
2,074,072 kbytes

Comment: and the threads details from jconsole are, 
Live threads: 201
Peak: 207
Daemon threads: 182
Total threads started: 2,770